# Dynamic query over web services

Tags: web-services

Does anyone have an idea how to implement a dynamic query over web services? For instance, taking an example like HQL I'd like to submit a string such as "Select Person.* from Person" and have a soap response returned containing an array of Person soap objects.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, but executing a dynamic query from a web-service is dangerous.  If your service executes the query directly, your clients could potentially send in deletes/updates/inserts/drop table/etc. and mess up your database.

I would recommend implementing more specific service methods that accepts specific arguments and returns type-safe objects or collections.

Comment: +1 classic SQL Injection. Don't send SQL over the wire like that. :D

Comment: I was only going to expose read only capability as a dynamic query.